# Insert email when creating account with rest api

Tags: sugarcrm

I am faced with a Sugar 6.3 CE installation, trying to create new accounts through rest api.

I am still on the learning curve for a lot of the innards of the CRM, and cannot figure out how to have the email inserted whith the rest of the account info upon creation with a REST call.

I have tried many different field values, and after catching that `$email1` was used in some snippet examples I saw on the sugarCRM site.  I have not found other mentions in the forums or in the docs yet.

The $parameters array used to configure the usual rest call to create an account in php with `REST` api looks like this and works fine, *except* for the $email1:

```
$parameters = array(
 'session' => $session,
 'module' => 'Contacts',
 'name_value_list' => array(

   array('name' => 'first_name', 'value' => 
     utf8_encode($contacts["Name"])),

   array('name' => 'last_name',  'value' =>
     utf8_encode($contacts["GivenName"])),
    array('name' => 'phone_work', 'value' =>
     utf8_encode($row->PrimaryPhoneAreaCode . ' ' .  $row->PrimaryPhone)),

   array('name' => 'phone_fax',  'value' => 
     utf8_encode($row->PrimaryFaxAreaCode . ' ' .  $row->PrimaryFaxNumber)),
    array('name' => 'title', 'value' => 
     utf8_encode($contacts["Title"])),

  /*
   * PROBLEM HERE!
   */
   array('name' => 'email1',     'value' => 
     utf8_encode($row->PrimaryEmail)),

   array('name' => 'primary_address_street', 'value'  => 
     utf8_encode($row->Address1) . '  ' . 
     utf8_encode($row->Address2)),
    array('name' => 'language',   'value' => 
     utf8_encode($row->Language)),

   array('name' => 'assigned_user_id', 'value' => 
     get_rep_id($row->Salesperson1Name, $sugarlink)),
   )
);
```

I would be curious, if someone has the trick. I tried to find to field for emails but it seems to be in separate tables. Any help / tips appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must add the email into emailadress database first, create contact and set a relationship between both ;-)

```
 $set_entry_parametersEADDR = array(
             "session" => $session_id,
             //The name of the module from which to retrieve records.
             "module_name" => "EmailAddresses",
             //Record attributes
             "name_value_list" => array(
            array('name' => 'email_address', 'value' => $email), 
            array('name' => 'email_address_caps', 'value' => strtoupper($email)),
            array('name' => 'invalid_email' , 'value' => 0),
            array('name' => 'opt_out', 'value' => 0), 
            array('name' => 'date_created' , 'value' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')),
            array('name' => 'date_modified', 'value' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')), 
            array('name' => 'deleted' , 'value' => 0),
             ),
        );

        $set_entry_resultEmailsAdd = call("set_entry", $set_entry_parametersEADDR, $url);
        print_r($set_entry_resultEmailsAdd);
        $Email_id = $set_entry_resultEmailsAdd->id;  

        $set_entry_parameters_contact = array(
                //session id
                "session" => $session_id,

                //The name of the module from which to retrieve records.
                "module_name" => "Contacts",

                //Record attributes
                "name_value_list" => array(
                  //to update a record, you will nee to pass in a record id as commented below
                  //array("name" => "id", "value" => "9b170af9-3080-e22b-fbc1-4fea74def88f"),
                  array("name" => "first_name", "value" => $prof["Prenom"]),
                  array("name" => "last_name", "value" => $prof["Nom"]),
                  array("name" => "login_c", "value" => $prof["Login"]),
                  //array("name" => "email1", "value" => $email),
                  array("name" => "fonction_c", "value" => "prof")
                     ),
                );

        $set_entry_result_contact = call("set_entry", $set_entry_parameters_contact, $url);    
        print_r($set_entry_result_contact);
        $contact_id = $set_entry_result_contact->id;  

        $set_relationship_parameters_email = array(
            'session' => $session_id,
            'module_name' => 'Contacts',
            'module_id' => $contact_id,
            'link_field_name' => 'email_addresses',
            'related_ids' => $Email_id,
        );

        $set_relationship_result_email = call("set_relationship", $set_relationship_parameters_email, $url);  
        print_r($set_relationship_result_email);
```

Comment: Yeah. There we go!  The code is not all that pretty but it *seems* like it does what it says on the tin.  Please don't wait 6 years next time ;o)

Answer (score 3):

If you are using REST API the **email1** will work for both *set* en *get* methods (just tested it).

Did not used the SOAP API as in your example, and suggest to migrate all to REST according to SugarCRM recommendations.

Answer (score 1):

Currently I think that not works with REST api but works with SOAP API. Could you try to use `email1_set_in_workflow` key instead of `email1`?
It's not a very good solution but perhaps that could unlock you pending a better way to do that in future release